# Is every non-trivial ideal in a commutative ring is a principal ideal?

Tags: ideals

I'm a bit lost... it seems every non-trivial ideal in a commutative ring is a principal ideal. but is it true? if not, could you pls give a counter example?

Comment: Take $(x, y) \subset k[x, y]$.

Comment: In addition to @Qiaochu's example, you could also take $(2,X)\subseteq \mathbb{Z}[X]$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan i'm beginner of algebra, could you pls elaborate a bit what is $(x,y)$ and what is $k[x,y]$?

Comment: @AmiteshDatta i'm beginner of algebra, could you pls elaborate a bit what is $(2,X)$ and what is $Z[X]$?

Comment: Dear @athos, $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is the polynomial ring over $\mathbb{Z}$ in one variable $X$. Also, $(2,X)$ is the ideal generated by $2,X\in \mathbb{Z}[X]$, that is, the set of all elements of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ of the form $2p + Xq$ for $p,q\in \mathbb{Z}[X]$.

Comment: Yes now I see it.... Principal ideal indicates one dimension, while a ring could have 2 dimensions... Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By non-trivial, do you an ideal that is not the whole ring itself? I'm going to proceed assuming that's what you mean.

If every ideal in a given integral domain $R$ is a principal ideal, then $R$ is a principal ideal domain, and then it's also a unique factorization domain. In $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$, for example, every ideal is a principal ideal.

But now consider $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$, which is neither a UFD nor a PID. $\langle 3 \rangle$ is a principal ideal but not a prime ideal. The ideal $\langle 3, 1 + \sqrt{-5} \rangle$, which consists of all numbers of the form $3a + b\sqrt{-5}$ with $\{a, b\} \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ is a prime ideal but not a principal ideal.

Comment: *Principal ideal ring. ($R$ need not be a domain.)

Comment: Alright, I'm going to change that to say "integral domain" rather than "ring." I hope integral domains are more accessible to beginners.